# Pyinstaller is unable to import custom commands of Django 2.1.5

Tags: django, python-3.6, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller for creating build for my project on ubuntu machine.
I have written one custom commands **createsappsuperuser** in django to create sime special users. To create the executable file, I am running my manage.spec file and the executable is getting created successfully. The location of that executable is in **dist folder**.

After that I am running **./dist/manage createsappsuperuser** which gives error like -

```
Unknown command: 'createsappsuperuser'. Did you mean createsuperuser?
Type 'manage help' for usage.
```

To solve the above issue, I tried adding my cusom command in the dict 
in **Pyinstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_django.py** file as because pyi_rth_django.py always return some static set of commands.

I have added it like **'createsappsuperuser': 'idmgmt'** in the dictionary. Here, **idmgmt** is my app name.

But the above solutions was valid for upto Django 1.8, and even the file "pyi_rth_django.py" says that it is tested with Django 1.8.

Then how should i do it in Django 2.1.5 ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is not working? What code did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, I have updated my question. Thanks